# Webpack 4 splitChunks and vendor bundle

Tags: webpack, chunks, webpack-4, vendor, entry-point

I don't get it whats up with this new Webpack 4 splitCunks and how to generate bundle and vendor files with it.
Until now I have been using it like this

```
entry: {
    vendor: [ '@babel/polyfill', 'react', 'react-dom', 'react-router-dom', ],
    bundle: [ './app.js', ],
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(buildPath, 'dist'),
    filename: 'js/[name].[chunkhash].js',
    chunkFilename: 'js/[name].[chunkhash].js',
    publicPath: '/',
  },

plugins: [
  new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendor',
      minChunks: Infinity,
    }),
]
```

Simple entry point with bundle and vendor where I added which packages I want them to be inside vendor file.

How am I supposed to achieve this with webpack 4?

This still works if I remove commonchunks but I don't know if its prefered way or not anymore.

I tried something like this by removing vendor from entry point and adding splitChunks but I only get one bundle.js file generated.

```
splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'async',
      minSize: 30000,
      maxSize: 0,
      minChunks: 1,
      maxAsyncRequests: 5,
      maxInitialRequests: 3,
      automaticNameDelimiter: '~',
      name: true,
      cacheGroups: {
        vendors: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          priority: -10,
          name: vendor
        },
        default: {
          minChunks: 2,
          priority: -20,
          reuseExistingChunk: true,
        },
      },
    },
```